# Problems of compilation with TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

When I try to compile my file using TexStudio it comes up with this message:
Error: Unable to run command: /Library/TeX/texbin/luatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file".tex
can someone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Please write in english here!

Comment: What exactly have you installed? This error usually comes up if you've only installed an editor but no latex. Texstudio is just one among many editors that can be used with latex, neither comes with a larex distribution, that needs to be installed separately.

Comment: I can see you're on a mac. If my assumption above is correct you should additionally install mactex (remember to update it after installation). Additionally are you sure it should be latex and not lualatex?